# what actually defines a limit?

Tags: limits, ratio

So recently I reviewed the concept of limit. I encountered a confusion: if a sequence has a common ratio of slightly over 1. It gradually approaches 1 as the ratio of the sequence is 
$$\sqrt{1/(b_n)^2+b_{n}^2}/(b_n)^2,$$

where $b_n$ is the previous term of the sequence. Thus the new number will be

$$\sqrt{1/(b_n)^2+b_{n}^2}/(b_n)$$

but it will also be greater than one. Suppose there are infinite terms in this sequence, will there be a limit of the sequence? What will it be?

Edit:  the first term of the equence is 1. Only real number will be allowed in the sequence( both rational and rrational.) the exact sequence is $b_{n+1}=\sqrt{1/(b_n)^2+b_{n}^2}/(b_n)$ and there are infinte terms  the sequence. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: Please state the exact definition of the sequence, presumably by a recurrence relation $b_{n+1}=f(b_n)$.

Comment: You have $b_{n+1} = \sqrt{1+1/(b_n)^4}$. If the limit $L$ does exist, it must satisfy $L = \sqrt{1+1/L^4}$. This equation has only one real root (it's the square root of a complicated number that's the root of a cubic equation) that's about $1.21$. Of course, whether the limit exists is a different question, and you haven't told us the initial condition yet (indeed, even whether $\{b_n\}$ is real-valued).